# Writing helper functions / code / interviews in docassemble, directly to data directory (i.e. bypassing the playground)?

Tags: docassemble

In the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66649886/how-to-organize-the-playground-in-docassemble-best-practices) it was suggested that advanced users might like to develop packages directly, rather than developing in the playground and then creating separate packages -- specifically, the idea was to create cross-package helper functions without having to package / repackage, etc.

A few questions here. Some of this is pretty "out of the box," so I'm happy to do my own experimentation / research, but just wanted to ask in case there are any known issues / thoughts / best practices that come to mind.

1. Is this the correct directory to be looking at for that suggestion: `/usr/share/docassemble/local3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docassemble/[[package-name]]/data`?
2. Is there any magic to that directory, or can I use `.../site-packages/docassemble/helpers` for development of helper functions / cross-use interview stuff, and then import into `.../data` as needed?
3. Is there a listing of the docassemble file structure somewhere in the docs (i.e. when you run the container)? There are various references to (eg.) `/usr/share/docassemble/config/`, `.../docassemble/backup`, etc., in the docs, but I haven't found anything for the whole filesystem, or the docassemble layer's filesystem (obviously not necessary to lay out `alpine`, for example).
4. Looking at the ["Anatomy of a docassemble package" page](https://docassemble.org/docs/packages.html#anatomy) of the docs, along with the ["Modules folder" page](https://docassemble.org/docs/playground.html#modules), I think the CWD for the purposes of imports to the `.yml` files is `.../data`?
5. If that's right, then if I were to create a `/usr/share/docassemble/local3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docassemble/helpers/helper.py` directory and file, I could then use something like the following to import `helper.py` in a fictional `interview.yml` file? Not saying that would be the best idea, but just asking if it might work to try to understand a bit more about docassemble... haven't fully thought through the workflow for something like this (i.e. if it might be better to just use the playground to package things up, or if there's another easier option).

```
---
modules:
    - .....helpers.helper
---
```

6. Presumably then I could also take the suggestion elsewhere in the docs and abstract away the code within the package by placing it in the `docassemble/packagename/data/` folder and import like this:

```
---
modules:
    - .module
---
```

I suppose I could even even structure my files like this `.../data/modules/module.py`, and then import with something like the following?

```
---
modules:
    - .modules.module
---
```

Happy to do my own experimentation / research, but just wanted to ask in case there are any known issues / thoughts that come to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `Dockerfile` runs `python3.8 -m venv --copies /usr/share/docassemble/local3.8`.  When it comes time to upgrade to Python 3.9, it will do `python3.9 -m venv --copies /usr/share/docassemble/local3.9`.  How packages are installed inside that virtual environment is up to the developers of Python and `pip`.
2. The directory `site-packages/docassemble/helpers` would be the directory for the Python package `docassemble.helpers`.  You could write such a package and publish it on PyPI (the name is not taken yet).
3. You could look at the [Installation page](https://docassemble.org/docs/installation.html) and/or the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/jhpyle/docassemble/blob/master/Dockerfile).
4. When you refer to data files in Python packages you can use a fully-qualified reference such as `docassemble.familylaw:data/questions/kids.yml`.  If you write `data/static/tweaks.css` it will assume you mean a file in the current package.  If you just give it a file name (e.g., `tweaks.css`) it will assume you mean a file in the current package and it will make an assumption about what data folder you are referring to based on the context.  If your Python package is called `docassemble.familylaw`, then the data folder is located at `docassemble/familylaw/data` inside the `docassemble.familylaw` package.
5. You could make a Python package called `docassemble.helpers` and install it, but bypassing docassemble's package installation system by writing files directly to the Python virtual environment is not advisable. Note that docassemble is a cloud application, so a docassemble "server" may be a cluster of machines.  The package management system ensures that you can do `docker stop`, `docker rm`, `docker pull`, and `docker run`, and your server will be up and running again with all the right Python packages, even if the `docker pull` results in an upgrade from Python 3.8 to Python 3.9.
6. The `modules` block has nothing to do with the `data` folder.  If `docassemble.xyz` is listed in a `modules` block, docassemble runs `from docassemble.xyz import *` and imports the module's exported names into the interview answer namespace.